# Dividing a large file in multithreaded application?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

I was asked this basic question in an interview which I couldn't answer:

> How can we divide a large file between multi threads to process it? If
>   we are running a multi threaded application and input is a large file
>   and we have to provide each thread a part of the file to make it fast.
>   How we can achieve it in Java?

Can anyone explain me how we will do this? Any example will also be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this answer `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927398/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-chunks-using-java-multithread`

Comment: ^ Please make that a link.

Comment: There's a fallacy here. The disk, and therefore the file, is not multithreaded. It's dubious whether multithreading it will go any faster. Possibly slower.

Comment: @EJP Let's assume disk can handle multithreaded.

Comment: Can you use Java8? if then why can not you look into steams. Huge file memory mapped files would be better

Comment: I note that systems like Hadoop make sure they store large files across multiple machines (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#HDFS) which suggests to me that the best way to solve this problem might be to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get 3 starting positions

```
    File f = new File("xxx");
    long size = f.length();
    long p1 = 0;
    long p2 = f.length() / 3;
    long p3 = p2 + f.length() / 3;
```

Pass position and length to read to thread, move file to position and read n bytes

```
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("xxx");
    FileChannel c= is.getChannel();
    c.position(position);
    // read ...
```

Comment: You mean `long p3 = f.length() - p2;` Your way, `p2 == p3`.

Comment: long p3 = p2 + f.length() / 3; this should be it

Comment: Thanks for adding an example. if possible, could you add more explanation step by step how will this work? And what position mean here as well? I have never used `position` and `FileChannel` before so any step by step explanation will be great help.

Comment: position is a starting point from where InputStream will read a next byte. When we first open FileInputStream position = 0; when we read 1 byte position moves to 1. FileChannel allows to set position to any location inside file. In our case we set thread 2 to position at 1/3 of the file length and tread 2 to position at 2/3 of the file length

Comment: Ok got it. And do we need to merge anything with this solution at the end of reading all the files by thread?

Comment: You should use ThreadPoolExecutor, submit 3 tasks concurrently, wait for 3 results. What to do with the results depends on the application logic

Comment: Would the IO really be concurrent?  Isn't all disk IO done synchronously?  My initial thought would be to do what @ism3l suggested because I thought disk IO would be done synchronously by the hardware.

Comment: It's up to the OS. Java will try to do it concurrently. Alternatevaly you can have a single reader which reads a chunk and sends it to a thread, then reads another and sends to another thread...

Answer (score 1):

In an interview the response should be that this is a consumer-producer problem.
So you should have 1 producer thread reading the file and put the lines in a syncronized collection like a Vector, and you could have n consumer threads taking the lines from the collection and process them.

If it helps to prepare another interview questions could be: Hyper-threading, deadlocks, busy waiting.

There are some books for interviews like cracking the code interview, or Java Programming Interviews Exposed.